# Sport SQL query improvement

Tags: java

I will appreciate if someone can help me find the right queries for my tables, as I have tried so often but just didn't work.

Comment: Show what you've tried, and someone will help you fix it. Don't just ask for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll cut you a break since MySQL can be difficult and confusing starting out. You should research how these queries work. If you're studying SQL: the way I learn most effectively, personally, is through lots of exercises which make me think about different sorts of SQL queries - so do a lot of exercises.

### Player names for both teams

> How can show all the players from both <s>games</s> teams by their names?

I'm going to assume you mean *teams*, not games. Given a game, do this:

```
SELECT Player.team_id AS team_id,
    Player.player_name AS player_name
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Game
    ON (
        (Game.Home_team_id = Player.team_id)
        OR (Game.Guest_team_id = Player.team_id))
WHERE Game.game_id = [YOUR GAME ID];
```

This will produce results like:

```
team_id     player_name
1           John Smith
1           Jane Doe
2           John Person
```

### Team with the most wins

> How can i find out the team who has more win than the rest of the teams?

Since there doesn't appear to be anything saying who won, I can't really tell you how to write such a query. There's only a single score field and I'm not sure what it contains. I can't really circle around that either, since the query would look radically different depending on what data's available to work from, and I don't like to make assumptions (it might be a waste of time for both of us).

If it contains, say, JSON or XML data, or some other data format containing a set of scores, you need to break that apart into its own cells. Storing a collection of data inside a table cell, like a JSON collection of scores for instance, is fine - as long as you *never, ever* need to query it. Once you need to query it, that turns into a mess, and you need to avoid that sort of situation.

Comment: Thank your for your help i have learn from ur query and used to sort out other issues. about the score, it has simple data as the one for player for both teams. I tried COUNT to count the result as win or lose by adding new attribute called home-team-result,guest-team-result,but didnt know how to put both of them in one query.i did count( h.home_team_result,a.away_team_result) where h.home-team_result and away_team_result='win' but it says invalid number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
select
  Case when Team.Team_id = Game.Guest_team_id then 'Guest' else 'Home' end as location,
  Team_name,
  Player_name
from Game
join Team on Team.Team_id in (Game.Home_team_id,Game.Guest_team_id)
join Player on Player.team_id = Team.Team_id
order by 1,3
```

2) Assume that `score` is net of Home_team score - Guest_team score:

```
select Team_Name, TotalPoints = sum(Points)
from (
  select 
    Team_Name, case when score > 0 then 2  
                    when score = 0 then 1 
                                   else 0 end as Points
  from Team join Game on Team.Team_id = Game.Home_team_id
  union all
  select 
    Team_Name, case when score < 0 then 2 
                    when score = 0 then 1 
                                   else 0 end as Points
  from Team join Game on Team.Team_id = Game.Guest_team_id
) T
GROUP BY Team_Name
order by 2 desc
LIMIT 1
```

This is readily modified to calculate any particular result variation of interest.

**Update** - After the clarification on `score`:

```
select Team_Name, TotalPoints = sum(Points)
from (
  select 
    Team_Name, case when home_team_score > guest_team_score then 1
                                                            else 0 
               end as Points
  from Team join Game on Team.Team_id = Game.Home_team_id
  union all
  select 
    Team_Name, case when home_team_score < guest_team_score then 1
                                                            else 0 
               end as Points
  from Team join Game on Team.Team_id = Game.Guest_team_id
) T
GROUP BY Team_Name
order by 2 desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, I was bored; and the claim that (2) was impossible riled me.

Comment: I never said it was impossible. I just didn't make any assumptions about what data's there, which is necessary for the query. If it was stored data, I could only give advice.

Comment: I've edited my answer so as to _not_ say it's impossible, and more just say what I meant - _I_ don't see a way to do it, since I don't know what's in there.

Comment: Thank your for help. for the score i have tried what u have suggested to me but couldtn figure it out.what i understood from total points is that the total score from both team to identify the winner?. can you make ur suggestion more clear please.

Comment: @sacha: So what exactly does `score` represent?

Comment: well, the score represent the number of goals scored by each team, and each team has its own score, but i dont want to use numeric number, instead of number i want to use win or lost, to use count query but it didnt want to work for me when i put count(h.home_team_score,A.away_team_score)

Comment: @sacha: Please list, **in the question** as an **update**, the new fields that have been added, to which tables, with their semantics.

Comment: its been updated, the 2 new fields are home_team_score,away-team-score. thx

Comment: Thank you Pieter, didnt want to work, i think im doin something wrong, i spent all day with it,so i will just leave it, thx