# SQL WORK improvement

Tags: mysql, sql

Player table:

```
player_ID
player_name
position_id
```

Position table:

```
position_ID
position_description
```

Team table:

```
TEAM_ID
TEAM_NAME
```

Game table:

```
Game_id
home_team_id
guest_team_id
score
location
date
```

Stats table

```
game_id
player_id
number of fouls
number of rebounds
```

I have tried the following query to find the various position that a player can play at them:

```
select  player.player_name,position.position_name
from player,position
where player.fname='John' and position_name='Guard,Midfield,Striker'
```

I have tried the following query to list the games date and location that has for example 5 fouls, i tried this query:

```
select game.date,location,number of fouls, 
from game,stats
where game.date=game.id
 and game.location=game.id
 and number of fouls > 5
group by game.date,game.location
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: I want to correct my mistakes, because my queries doesnt work

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329574/sport-sql-query-improvement

Comment: what is your problem? i am yet searching. did not found anything

Comment: @sacha please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for some pointers on how to ask proper questions.

Comment: Well, i want to get various position that a particular player can play, but the query i did didnt work. and for the second query to list all games with 5 fouls didnt work at all

Comment: Is that field seriously named `number of fouls` including spaces?

Comment: yes bcz that field will help find out the fouls made but the space is not necessary

Comment: You do realize that because of the spaces the SQL engine has no clue which words are parts of the name, and which belong to the SQL syntax? It's the digital equivalent of telling a human "I helped my uncle Jack off a horse" - it's impossible to determine the true meaning of what you said without extra hints. Never, ever, use spaces in column names, use camelCasing, PascalCasing or underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start at least, but first a couple of points:

1. I'd avoid column names with spaces. MySQL will handle them if you use backticks, but I find them to be more trouble than they're worth.
2. These are not extremely difficult queries. If you have the opportunity, spend an hour or so doing a basic MySQL tutorial. The [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/examples.html) has some examples.
3. When you select from two or more tables you almost always want to `JOIN` them. The tutorials will cover this.

OK, here are the queries...

Player and positions they can play:

```
SELECT
  Player.Player_ID,
  Player.Player_Name,
  Position.Position_Description
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Position ON Player.Position_ID = Position.Position_ID
WHERE Player.FName = 'John'
  AND Position_Name IN ('Guard', 'Midfield', 'Striker')
```

Games with more than 5 fouls:

```
SELECT
  Game.Date,
  Game.Location,
  SUM(Stats.`number of fouls`) AS TotalFouls
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Stats ON Game.Game_ID = Stats.Game_ID
GROUP BY Game.Date, Game.Location
HAVING SUM(Stats.`number of fouls`) > 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however the position query didn't work for me, it gives me no row selected, i have added a primary key to position to make a composite key made of player_id and position_id but still not working,I think the way i designed it is wrong but i will sort it out. thank you

Comment: Do you get anything for the position query if you take away some of the `WHERE` logic? For example, you may not have a player with first name John who's a guard, midfielder or striker. Also if you have a `Position_ID` in the `Player` table, make sure the `Position_ID` also exists in the `Position` table. Good luck!

Comment: Yes i did try without including the player name,so what i did now is i removed the position_id from player and i have it now just in position, so to link them im trying to use position_id and player_id as a composite key to make it work, I removed position_id bcz it was repeating it self in the player table and left just in position table, Hope it will work!

Comment: can you please check the position query with me again, as it didnt want to work